# A closed subscheme that is not the intersection of closed locally principal subschemes?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I've always assumed that not every closed subscheme is the intersection of locally principal subschemes, i.e. that there is some scheme $X$ with a closed subscheme $L\subseteq X$ such that $L$ is not the intersection of closed subschemes $K\subseteq X$ for which there exist covers by open affines $X=\bigcup U_i$ such that the defining (possibly improper) ideals $I_j\subseteq R_j$ of the closed $K|_{U_j}\subseteq U_j=\mathrm{Spec}R_i$ are principal ideals of $R_j$).

However, I don't actually know the counter-example off the top of my head.

Comment: @Krish I don't see an answer to my question there: it's shown that a certain Weil divisor on an affine scheme is not locally principal, but that's not a countexample for me because I only want it to be an *intersection* of locally principal subschemes, which it is because it's a closed subscheme of an *affine* scheme...